# I'm trying to download a list of photos from URL displayed in collectionview, but I cannot figure out a way to do this

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get several URLs of photos from a server and display them in a collectionview. The thing is, they provide a api called 
"findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" to let me download URLs from server. It automatically download from server in background.I'm trying to use dispatch_async but it seems has some trouble with collectionview. Any ideas?

```
 BmobQuery *picturesB = [BmobQuery queryWithClassName:@"AssetPicture"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
[picturesB findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error)
 {
     for (BmobObject *obj in array)
     {
         [photourl addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
         NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl[i]]];
         [self.arr addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];  
     }     
 }];//Bmob query        


if(self.arr!=nil)
   {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{         
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell"]; 
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];   
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Header"];
       });// dispatch
   }//if
  });//dispatch

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageView.image = [self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"photo done");
cell.descLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: show your collectionview cellforitem

Comment: Did you try to reload collection once download of images is completed?

Comment: Where do you create your `self.arr`?

Comment: What is your trouble with collectionview? Please show me your collectionview.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and everyone else! I just need to reload the data at the end of findobjectsinbackground.